# Is there a function in python that returns true if all members of an iterable are true?

Tags: python, lambda, reduce, hasattr

I'm tryng to learn different ways to do simple things in python, while also learning a bit about some functional practices. I have some numbers that the user inputs, and I want to know if they really are numbers. I've come up with this kind of classic solution:

```
def foo(list_of_inputs):
    for n in list_of_inputs:
       if not hasattr(n, "real"):
           # some number is not a number!
           return False
    # all are numbers
    return True
```

But then, I figured out this other "thing" that may have some potential:

```
def foo(list_of_inputs):
    bool_list = map(lambda input: hasattr(input, "real"), list_of_inputs)
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x == y, bool_list)
```

I think that maybe a function that returns "True" if all members of a collection, iterable, or whatever the correct concept I'm looking for, are "True", may already be something somewhat common, and also, this second attempt doesn't return when a "False" is found, while the classic one does... But I find it elegant, and maybe that is because I'm not there yet with programming in general.

So my question is: what's the "probably better" way to do this?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all

Comment: You would usually use `all` with a generator expression: `all(hasattr(input, 'real') for input in list_of_inputs)`.

Comment: That is actually the best way I've seen so far, even if negates where I thought I would find it (behind some functional related practices). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, the `all` function will do what you want. What you describe you're trying to do can also be done with the `str.isnumeric()` function.

```
def foo(listOfInputs):
    return all(map(str.isnumeric,listOfInputs))
```

**Edit**: I'm finding that it fails on `['1','2','3.14','4']` which is a little annoying. Maybe someone can come up with a cleverer solution than this, but I decided to wrap a slightly modified approach in a `try`:

```
def foo(listOfInputs):
    try:
        return all(map(float,listOfInputs))
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

That works on:

```
['1','2','-3','4']
['1','2','3.14','4']
```

Comment: Nice to know about isnumeric(), It wasn't working, but it seems that it is because I'm on python 2.7.5 and it has to be unicode. Thanks a lot. Maybe I should just forget about trying to avoid testing all if unnecesary, at least for now.

Comment: Ah my bad. testing user input is a good practice, but you can easily "go down the rabbit hole" checking for any possible thing a user could enter. Example: what if someone enters `1,000,000`? Or `1,199.99`? Or what if they're in Europe and they type `1.000.000,99`? These should all be valid, in theory, but writing code to test all of these could become a whole [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) thing.

Comment: Yeah,but hey, there are some syntactic constrains, so maybe the best way to deal with those edge cases is to inform how input is expected. I'm from Europe actually, so I get how the example you mention can be a problem.

Comment: You don't need the lamba in `foo`. `return all(map(str.isnumeric, listOfInputs))`

Comment: That's really cool, thanks for the tip. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like the built-in [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) function?

> Return True if all elements of the iterable are true (or if the iterable is empty). Equivalent to:

Comment: Yeah, all(map(lambda x: hasattr(x, "real"), list_of_inputs)) looks better, Thanks! I should check the bultins more often... But there's still the thing with checking all instead of returning when any is "False". Thank you though

Comment: @ferhtgoldaraz `(map(lambda x: hasattr(x, "real"), list_of_inputs))` looks better than the short and sweet `all`?

Comment: No, it's just that I need to build the collection of booleans, and call all() on it... Don't I?